# Is there a vector of magnitude $0$?

Tags: vectors

(1) If I have a vector of the form $\vec v=a\hat\imath + b\hat\jmath$ and both $a$ and $b$ equal $0$ such that $\vec v=0$, is it still considered a vector?

(2) And, if so, does that make any value that is equal to $0$ a vector?

Comment: It is the $\mathbf 0$ vector.  It is absolutely a vector, and it has unique properties much like the number $0$ has unique properties in the real numbers.

Comment: Regarding your second question, is your confusion that $\mathbf 0$ doesn't have a *direction*? Is this in the context of pure mathematics (vector is an object in a vector space) or physics (vector has magnitude and direction)?

Comment: Note that $\vec x$ and $\mathbf x $ use to represent the same thing.

Comment: (One important property is that $$||\mathbf 0|| = 0$$ ...that is, the magnitude of *the zero vector* is zero.)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

(1) Yes that it is still a vector, albeit a degenerate one.

(2) The vector $0 \hat{i} + 0 \hat{j}$ is technically a different object from the scalar/number $0$, even though they are often denoted the same (this is called abuse of notation). This is why I often prefer to write $\vec{0}$ for the vector $0 \hat{i} + 0 \hat{j}$, in order to differentiate from the number $0$.

Comment: I should note that it is degenerate in the sense that it does not have a direction. Given any vector $v$ not equal to $\vec{0}$, one can define the direction of $v$ to be $\displaystyle\frac{v}{|| v ||}$ where $||v||$ denotes the norm of $v$, i.e. $\sqrt{v_1^2 + v_2^2 + v_3^2}$. This construction is not defined for the vector $\vec{0}$ however, which is why in a very literal sense it does not have a direction. If, at any point of a curve, $\vec{0}$ is the tangent vector, then the tangent is said to be undefined, since it has no clear direction. An example is a curve with a cusp.